# Problem with drop function after update pandas to latest version

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I update my pandas to version 2.0.3 and now the drop that I am using returns an error.
This is my drop code.

```
some_race.drop(some_race.columns.difference(
                    ['nr_zwierz', 'rasa', 'blup_zwh', 'h_pd', 'przyrost', 'h_pm', 'proc_mies', 's1', 's2']), 1,
                    inplace=True)
```

some_race is a DataFrame that works in a loop, drop should delete all columns except this one inside list.

This solution was working well before the update, but now I get this error:

```
DataFrame.drop() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given
```

I tried to change the code to:

```
some_race = some_race.drop(some_race.columns.difference(
                    ['nr_zwierz', 'rasa', 'blup_zwh', 'h_pd', 'przyrost', 'h_pm', 'proc_mies', 's1', 's2']), 1)
```

but I get the same error.
I could go back to a previous version, but I can't remember what version it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `axis=1` for keyword argument for [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
some_race.drop(some_race.columns.difference(
                ['nr_zwierz', 'rasa', 'blup_zwh', 'h_pd', 'przyrost', 'h_pm', 'proc_mies', 's1', 's2']), axis=1,
                inplace=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

[mlodycezar's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17341789/mlodycezar) answer is correct and just added the explanation here:

In pandas, the axis parameter in the drop() function specifies the axis along which to drop labels or indexes. The axis parameter can take two values:

axis=0 (default): It refers to the rows or index labels.
axis=1: It refers to the columns.
When you use axis=1 in the drop() function, you are indicating that you want to drop columns from your DataFrame or Series.